# GET request to RESTful Web service doesn't return private variables

Tags: java, xml, rest, get

I'm trying to learn the implementation of RESTful Web services using JAX-RS. I was following [this tutorial here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaZdlJSts5A&index=14&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn) for that. In this tutorial, you can see that a `GET` request returns all the private variables of a class. However in my case, it doesn't. When I try, it returns a blank screen. Then when I change some of the members to public, the request returns only those member variables.

Below are my files:

**MovieObject.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class MovieObject {

    private String movieName;
    private String yearOfRelease;
    private String movieRating;

    public MovieObject(){

    }

    public MovieObject(String movieName, 
            String yearOfRelease, 
            String movieRating){

        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.yearOfRelease = yearOfRelease;
        this.movieRating = movieRating;
    }

    public String getMovieName(){
        return movieName;
    }


    public String getYearOfRelease(){
        return yearOfRelease;
    }

    public String getMovieRating(){
        return movieRating;
    }
}
```

**ResourceHandler.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/movies")
public class ResourceHandler {

    ListMovies listMovies = new ListMovies();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<MovieObject> getListOfMovies(){
        MovieObject mv1 = new MovieObject("The Independence Day 1", "1996", "7");
        MovieObject mv2 = new MovieObject("The Independence Day 2", "2016", "4");

        List<MovieObject> listOfMovies = new ArrayList<MovieObject>();

        listOfMovies.add(mv1);
        listOfMovies.add(mv2);

        return listOfMovies;
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Jersey RESTful Web Application!</h2>
    <p><a href="webapi/myresource">Jersey resource</a>
    <p>Visit <a href="http://jersey.java.net">Project Jersey website</a>
    for more information on Jersey!

    <p> Get list of movies <a href="webapi/movies"> here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.auro.self.movielib</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The following output is what I get when I run it on Tomcat 8.0

[image]

As you can see, I just get the `public` member variables (7 and 4 in this case) of the class and not the `private` ones.

But in the tutorial above, the request successfully returns all the `private` variables. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I can not see any public member variable in your code?

Answer (score 0):

While your code example is inconsistent,

```
new MovieObject("The Independence Day 1", "1996", "7");
```

uses 4 paramenters, while the constructor accepts only 3, you should add

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MovieObject {

@XmlAttribute
private String movieName;
@XmlAttribute
private String yearOfRelease;
@XmlAttribute
private String movieRating;
```

or alternatively

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MovieObject {

@XmlElement
private String movieName;
@XmlElement
private String yearOfRelease;
@XmlElement
private String movieRating;
```

That should solve your problem